# Tensorflow: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'DirectoryIterator' and 'float'

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

I have seen a number of people with this error, and I don't see how their answers apply to mine.

Working on a machine learning project to categorize flowers.

```
history = model.fit_generator(
          train_data_gen,
          steps_per_epoch=int(np.ceil(train_data_gen / float(batch_size))),
          epochs=epochs,
          validation_data=val_data_gen,
          validation_steps=int(np.ceil(val_data_gen / float(batch_size)))
          )
```

Returns error.

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'DirectoryIterator' and
> 'float'

The rest of my code is on Github.

https://github.com/ResponsiveWebApps/Categorize_Flowers/blob/master/Flower_Categorize.ipynb

I am new to TensorFlow so I don't know how to fix this. Any help would be great, thanks.

Comment: Can you add the entire error traceback?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was missing packages. Fixed now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The `train_data_gen` is a directory iterator, not a value which can be divided with.

If you want to have a length of the directory iterator use method `.n`.

**Code:**

```
history = model.fit(
    train_data_gen,
    steps_per_epoch=int(np.ceil(train_data_gen.n / float(batch_size))),
    epochs=epochs,
    validation_data=val_data_gen,
    validation_steps=int(np.ceil(val_data_gen.n / float(batch_size)))
)
```

Also, looking at your code, you have specified input shape as `(150,150,3)` but in the generator, you have specified image size as `(100,100)`.